# Finding the average speed when only speed is given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The respective ratio between the speeds of a car, a jeep and tractor is 3:5:2. The speed of the jeep is 250 percent of the speed of the tractor which covers 360 km in 12 hours. What is the average speed of car and jeep together ?

**My Approach:**

Let the speed of car be 3x

Let the speed of jeep be 5x

Let the speed of tractor be 2x

It's already given that tractor completes 360 km in 12 hours.

Applying the formula, **speed * time = distance**

**speed of tractor = $\frac{distance}{time}$ = $\frac{360}{12}$ = 30km/hr**

Therefore 2x = 30 => x=15

Speed of car = 3 * 15 = 45 km/hr

Speed of jeep = 5 * 15 = 75 km/hr

**Average speed = $\frac{totaldistance}{totaltime}$**

Let,

Distance covered by Car be = a

Distance covered by jeep be = b

**Total distance = a+b**

Time = $\frac{distance}{speed}$

Time(t1) covered by car =$\frac{a}{45}$

Time(t2) covered by jeep =$\frac{b}{75}$

**Total time =$\frac{a}{45}$ + $\frac{b}{75}$ = $\frac{5a+3b}{225}$ (by taking lcm)**

Now even if i apply these values to Average speed, I am not getting anywhere.

**When i google this question, the solution contains this formula.
Average speed  = $\frac{speed1+speed2}{2}$**
Thus giving the answer as $\frac{45+75}{2}$=60km/hr.

If possible i want to know how this formula was derived [Average speed  = $\frac{speed1+speed2}{2}$] ?

I don't understand. Please help .

[Update]

[Link] https://www.bankersadda.com/p/night-class-quantitative-aptitude-for_47.html ( Question 1)

Comment: What does the "average speed of car and jeep together" even mean??

Comment: Average speed of the two vehicles(car +  jeep). I think

Comment: Usually in time/speed/distance problems the average speed is total distance divided by time, it seems that you used this definition. Google answer just gives the average of two speeds, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @vasya i don't understand. Isn't Average speed = total distance / total time always.

Comment: I think I understand OP's method, at least. OP is fixing distances $d_a, d_b$ for two vehicles $A$, $B$ to travel and then dividing $d_a+d_b$ by the total travel time of the vehicles. But this approach can yield any result between the vehicles' velocities $v_a$ and $v_b$. Higher values of the ratio $d_a/d_b$ weight the speed of car $A$ more heavily. If $d_a$ and $d_b$ are chosen in proportion to $v_a$ and $v_b$, so the vehicles have equal travel times, then we get the arithmetic mean $60$ of the velocities; if $d_a = d_b$, then we get the harmonic mean $56.25$.

Comment: "When I google this question ...". It would be much more useful to paste the exact URL of the site you get the answer from, rather than say how you found that site.

Comment: @DavidK   Question Link: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CIzCCwAAQBAJ&pg=SA12-PA19&lpg=SA12-PA19&dq=the+ratio+of+the+speeds+of+car,jeep+and+tractor&source=bl&ots=2DtouIBL83&sig=-1u2srmGlg9wih452VgXn5J8z3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRhKqxp83cAhXKwI8KHZGODN0Q6AEwC3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20ratio%20of%20the%20speeds%20of%20car%2Cjeep%20and%20tractor&f=false Question.No 88

Comment: @DavidK Answer Link: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CIzCCwAAQBAJ&pg=SA12-PA31&dq=Required+average+speed+of+the+car+and+the+jeep&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimp6Pups3cAhUQTY8KHTWBBc4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Required%20average%20speed%20of%20the%20car%20and%20the%20jeep&f=false (Answer.No 88)

Comment: Those links do not exactly bring me to question number 88 in any book, but that is not surprising since their purpose is to sell the book, not give away the contents. Am I correct in inferring that the question is from a guide to preparing for a standardized exam in India? In that case, the reason the question is to be interpreted according to the given answer is because the author of the book believes the setters of the examination would interpret it that way.

Comment: @DavidK Then check this link Question 1 https://www.bankersadda.com/p/night-class-quantitative-aptitude-for_47.html

Answer (score 1):

The confusion you are running into is related to the following problem:

> A runner runs a lap on a 400 meter track: For the first 200 meters, the runner has the wind in his back, and the runner is able to run at a speed of 10 meters per second. For the next 200 meters, however, the runner is running into the wind, and so the runner ends up running only 8 meters per second. What is the average speed of the runner?

One reaction may be to say that the runner runs at an average speed of 9 meters per second: the average of 8 and 10.  However, if we calculate the average speed of the runner fore the whole lap, we have to understand that the runner will be running at the slower speed for a longer period than that the runner runs at the greater speed. Hence, the average speed will be closer to 8 meters per second than to 10 meters per second. Indeed, the runner covers the first 200 meters in 20 seconds, and the second 200 meters in 25 seconds, for a total time of 45 seconds, resulting in an average speed of about 8.88 meters per second.

OK .... but what does this all mean as far as your question goes?  I would say that the question is rather ambiguous in exactly these two ways. Maybe it is asking about the average of the speeds of the car and jeep ... which was the 'Google' answer.  On the other hand, maybe we are asked to compute the average speed between the car and the jeep over some specific distance, compatible to how we computed the average speed of the runner over the whole 400 meter lap. ... And this is what you did .. and of course you got a different answer given that the car took a longer time covering that same distance than the jeep. So .. what were we being asked?  I don't know ... I must say, I find this:

> 'What is the average speed of car and jeep together ?'

really quite unclear!

Comment: Another possible "average speed" is the total momentum of the car and jeep divided by their total mass. And we could go on like that. I would consider this to be an idiomatic problem for this particular kind of examination, whose "correct" solution is knowable only by having familiarity with the answer keys (or official review booklets) for past examinations from the same source. In other words, the solution uses the simple arithmetic mean of the two speeds because the examiners said so.

Answer (score 0):

> If possible i want to know how this formula was derived [Average speed
>   = $\frac{speed1+speed2}{2}$] ?

This is just the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of two values, here two velocities:
$$
\bar{v} = (v_1 + v_2) / 2
$$

Comment: @mvm but why the arthmetic mean formula was applied here in the above problem?

Comment: “average” is the informal name for calculating the arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 0):

Speed of tractor = 360/12 = 30 kmph
let the speed of Car, jeep and tractor are 3x, 5x and 2x respectively. 
So 2x = 30 kmph
x= 15 kmph
Thus speed of car and jeep will be 45 kmph and 75 kmph respectively.